# Removing data in ObjectBox based on Id

Tags: android, android-database, objectbox

I would like to remove the data on my ObjectBox database in Android based on its Id. Is this correct?

```
Box<Cart> box = ObjectBox.get().boxFor(Cart.class);
    Cart order = box.get(id);
    box.remove(order);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove` method is overloaded and there are variants accepting the following arguments:

- entity object
- ID (long)
- java.util.Collection objects
- long... ids
- T... objects

Thus, you can directly remove by ID like this:

```
box.remove(id);
```

For more details, please check the [API docs of the Box class](https://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/Box.html).